# Placing variable in single quotes

Tags: python

I am receiving an integer error when reading from my CSV sheet. Its giving me problems reading the last column. I know theres characters in the last column but how do I define `digit` as a character. The API function `psspy.two_winding_chg_4` requires an input using single quotes `' '` as shown below in that function(3rd element of the array)

[image: excel sheet]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Desktop\win4.py", line 133, in <module>
psspy.two_winding_chng_4(from_,to,'%s'%digit,[_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i],[_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f, max_value, min_value,_f,_f,_f],[])
File ".\psspy.py", line 25578, in two_winding_chng_4
TypeError: an integer is required
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'T1'
```

The code:

```
for row in data:
    data_location, year_link, from_, to, min_value,max_value,name2,tla_2,digit = row[5:14]
    output = 'From Bus #: {}\tTo Bus #: {}\tVMAX: {} pu\tVMIN: {} pu\t'
    if year_link == year and data_location == location and tla_2==location:
       from_=int(from_)
       to=int(to)
       min_value=float(min_value)
       max_value=float(max_value)
       digit=int(digit)
       print(output.format(from_, to, max_value, min_value))
       _i=psspy.getdefaultint()
       _f=psspy.getdefaultreal()
       psspy.two_winding_chng_4(from_,to,'%s'%digit,[_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i],[_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f, max_value, min_value,_f,_f,_f],[])
```

Comment: `T1` is a string. You need to remove the `T` in order to cast it to an int. In this case you can just take the last element of that string. `int(item[-1])`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and probable most usable option would be to used your own function to filter on only digits. Example:

```
def return_digits(string):
    return int(''.join([x for x in string if x.isdigit()]))
```

Comment: `FATAL: Circuit identifier is more than two characters   (002069)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    psspy.two_winding_chng_4(from_,to,"'{}'".format(digit),[_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i],[_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f, max_value, min_value,_f,_f,_f],[])
  File ".\psspy.py", line 25588, in two_winding_chng_4
psspy.Two_Winding_Chng_4Error: two_winding_chng_4 Error: ierr=2
Couldn't open Python file:C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Desktop\win4.py
Executing Python file:C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Desktop\win4.py`

Comment: Sorry was on holiday for a few days. Obviously this needs only to be applied on the column containing the data as in column  'N'. This seems to however come from the API. You will probable need to implement it there. Strange that you do get a file error though...